Mother and daughter dead, hands tied together with barbed wire
I can't find this movie, for the life of me.
Initially, I believed the main character was Jeff Goldblum, but I have searched through his filmography with no luck.
The father enters the house to find his wife and daughter, dead, in praying position, with their hands tied together with barbed wire. The elder son is locked in his room, and suicides by stabbing himself with a ceremonial lance of some sort, in the heart. Then a trip to hell is shown, along with the credits... Any ideas??

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

My first thought is Hideaway
It has Jeff Goldblum in it, the bad guy does murder two women at the beginning of the film and gets a ride to Hell after stabbing himself in the heart with a ceremonial dagger. 

Yes! That is the movie! Thanks ,am!!}
